# Cache-Control headers inside <If> and <Else> conditionals are being ignored in htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cache-control

I've been trying to figure this one out for a few days now and have finally made a simplified enough test environment so that I can post this question with several examples.

The problem I'm running into is that my htaccess file is ignoring both the `<If>` and `<Else>` conditions. I am using Apache version 2.4.29 which does support this feature. Likewise, when I save the htaccess file, I do not get a 500-level error– the site works just fine (besides these being ignored).

My use case is that I'd like to listen for a query parameter and change the Cache-Control header based on whether that query parameter exists. I'm sure others would disagree with this premise and while I'm curious what a better solution would be, I would like to get to the bottom of this particular issue.

I've tried feeding several conditions to the `<If>` thinking that maybe it just didn't like the format or that I was doing something wrong there, but I've now simplified it to be simply `<If false>` to try to force the `<Else>` side of the conditional. No matter what I do, neither side of the conditional is working– it is simply ignored completely.

Am I doing something wrong? I believe my syntax [matches the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#else), but maybe I'm missing something... While I do have a lot of experience writing .htaccess files, I will admit I am far from an Apache expert.

## Test cases

I made a webpage that simply loads a single `image.png` file and I read the Cache-Control header in Chrome DevTools.

---

### Example A

.htaccess file contents:

```
<FilesMatch "png">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=123, public"
</FilesMatch>

<If false>
    <FilesMatch "png">
        Header unset Cache-Control
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    </FilesMatch>
</If>
<Else>
    <FilesMatch "png">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"
    </FilesMatch>
</Else>
```

**Expected:** The `Cache-Control` `max-age` should be `31536000`

**Actual:** The `Cache-Control` `max-age` is `123`

[image: max-age is 123]

---

### Example B

.htaccess file contents:

```
<If false>
    <FilesMatch "png">
        Header unset Cache-Control
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    </FilesMatch>
</If>
<Else>
    <FilesMatch "png">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"
    </FilesMatch>
</Else>
```

**Expected:** The `Cache-Control` `max-age` should be `31536000`

**Actual:** No `Cache-Control` header exists at all

[image: No cache-control header at all]

---

**Edit: A clue has emerged** that I am able to use 301 RedirectMatch inside the If/Else conditions, so it seems like the cache control headers are what is being ignored from within the conditionals... If that is the case, I'm curious what other options I have to make my use case (described above) work.

**Edit 2: Another clue** is that without the `<FilesMatch>` line, the Cache-Control max-age header is applied as expected (just not to the right files).

Answer (score 0):

So I found a work-around for my specific use-case which is why I am "answering" my own question, but I am not "accepting" this answer as it does not resolve the core problem. I wanted to provide this for anyone who stumbles upon this issue in the future.

What I found was that `<FilesMatch>` was what was being ignored inside of `<If>` and `<Else>` conditions. Redirects and headers could be set without a problem within them.

So for my use-case, I flipped the logic around. I set the regular cache lengths as I wanted for individual file types using `<FilesMatch>` (outside of any conditionals). Then, I added an `<If>` condition to check for the query string, and if true it would unset all Cache-Control headers (so no FilesMatch as it was for all files).

Here is an example of what I'm now doing for my work-around (in the same format as the above examples):

```
# Set the cache headers as desired for individual files
<FilesMatch "png">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=123, public"
</FilesMatch>

# When this condition is true unset all of the caches (to be replaced with a query string detection)
<If true>
    # Notice no FilesMatch here– it affects all files
    Header unset Cache-Control
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
</If>
```

Again, this does not actually answer the core question, so I am not going to "accept" my own answer, but I wanted to provide it for anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use `if/else` for `.png` files like this:

```sh
<FilesMatch "\.png$">
   <If false>
        Header unset Cache-Control
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
   </If>
   <Else>
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"
   </Else>
</FilesMatch>
```

Expectedly it will set `Cache-Control: max-age=31536000, public` for all `.png` files.

Comment: Good thinking, thanks. That might get a little complex at scale (with many different cache lengths for many files), but this is a great thought– I appreciate it!

Comment: Do you want different cache setting for different file types?

Comment: I use varying cache lengths for different files, so this would work, but I would need to have the "unset" If condition inside each file group regex. Like I said– only adds a little complexity; still a viable solution.